# AMS points as taxable income when living and paying taxes in EU

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, foreign-income

I have been invited by [Mathematical Reviews](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html) to perform reviews of articles.  As compensation, I received some [AMS points](http://www.ams.org/membership/amspoints), which are redeemable as credit toward future purchases of books, etc, from the American Mathematical Society.  However, I have read on the MathRev page that AMS points are considered taxable income in the US.

I live and pay taxes in the Netherlands but also I had never lived and worked in the US.

Do I need to report these points as taxable income to the US tax authorities?  If so, how?

Comment: I think that information on the AMS web page is directed at US citizens and residents.  Since you are neither, as I understand it, it would be taxable by the US only if it is [US source income](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-aliens-source-of-income).  But the source is determined by where you *performed* the work, which was presumably at your home or office in the Netherlands, not inside the US.  If so then you have no obligation at all to the US tax authorities.  You should still check if it is taxable by the Netherlands.

Comment: @NateEldredge I suspect that over at Money SE users might not be familiar at all with AMS points (honestly, I have no idea what they are either).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: AMS is the American Mathematical Society, and AMS points are just a form of "store credit", redeemable for credit toward purchases from the AMS (books, subscriptions, membership fees, etc).  The Money.SE folks would have no problem with the concept if OP would just add a sentence to describe how the points work.

Comment: I edited to add an explanation and links.

Comment: @NateEldredge I won't migrate it there because at the moment I couldn't reach out a Money mod to see if it's on topic for them, and blind migrations are generally frowned upon. If you think it's off-topic here, I suggest you to vote to close this. If, instead, you're sufficiently familiar with Money SE to be confident that it'd be on topic there, let me know and I'll migrate.

Comment: Note also that whether it's on topic there doesn't imply it's off-topic here, and in such a case it'd be better not to migrate.

Comment: I suggest reaching out to a tax consultant in your country. I am almost certain you don't need to worry about US income tax, but would think almost all sources of income are taxable in your home country. Of course there are exceptions, thresholds, lots of details and rules, but do you rather trust someone's anonymous opinion on the internet or a trained professionell?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, especially a tax lawyer, but in the US, when total US income below a certain level there is no need to report anything. [See this for example](https://www.thebalance.com/are-you-required-to-file-a-tax-return-3192868)

For some purposes, if you are paid and taxes are withheld from your earnings, you can file to recover those funds if your total income is low. I doubt that is an issue here since the points have no intrinsic cash value.

You can probably just ignore the issue.

There is more information directly [from AMS](https://www.ams.org/membership/amspoints). Note that if you don't use them then they have no cash value at all, so become moot for tax reasons.

Comment: The fililng threshold described there is for 'resident' US income tax -- more exactly, while most countries tax income of residents (whether citizen or not), US applies 'resident' tax to all income of citizens and 'lawful permanent residents' residing _anywhere_ AND noncitizens (aliens) who are _considered_ resident (according to a formula that doesn't always correspond to actual residence) -- that's form 1040 (or 1040SR or in past years 1040A or 1040EZ). Non-citizen non-residents, defined as NonResident Alien = NRA, are taxed only on US-source income on form 1040NR (or formerly 1040NR-EZ) ...

Comment: ... and do not get any standard deduction, and mostly don't get itemized deductions either, so there is no filing threshold. _Some_ types of income paid to NRAs has withholding at source, which can often be exact (which 'resident' withholding rarely is  because 'resident' tax is more complicated), and _if_ the source withholding was correct then NRA isn't required to file (regardless of amount). But this Q doesn't indicate any such withholding.